# AJAX not displaying in chrome, every other browser is fine

Tags: html, ajax, google-chrome, jquery

I'm having a bit of an issue with a site displaying properly in Chrome. AJAX loads but doesn't make the final call to display in Chrome only. I've tested in Safari and Firefox and it works just fine.

I'm a bit new and don't have the tools to detect browser specific errors and was hoping someone on here could. The site is

http://www.veracitycolab.com

As you'll see, the page content loads in FF and Safari, however it doesn't get to its final display point in Chrome. Any help you can provide would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set `#main` css from `opacity:0` to `opacity:1` and it work fine in `Chrome`